# Using alternative to try catch exception for end of page link

Tags: java, selenium

Requirement: Go to the link which is a job search for last 3 days. 
1) Print job descriptions
2) Click on the next link to go to next page until you reach the last page

Problem: I am using try catch for no such element found for next link when I reach the last page. Using this solution it stops the script, by looking at the JUNIT bar you will not know if the test passed or failed.It is a grey bar since as I used exit. How can I make this code better so that I  do not have to use that try catch and see a green bar for a passing test?

Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class QAJob {

    @Test
    public void jobSearch(){
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.indeed.com/jobs?as_and=qa+engineer&as_phr=&as_any=&as_not"
                + "=&as_ttl=&as_cmp=&jt=all&st=&salary=&radius=10&l=Bellevue%2C+WA&fromage=7&limit"
                + "=10&sort=date&psf=advsrch");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //code to scroll down to find the rest pages link
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");

        // Find and print the number of pages for the search
        List<WebElement> search_pages=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div [contains(@class,'pagination')]//a"));

        System.out.println("Number of pages found for this search " + search_pages.size());

        while(search_pages.size()!=0){
            List<WebElement> job_desc=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div [contains(@id,'p')][contains(@class,'row')]"));

            for(WebElement e:job_desc){
                String str_job_desc=e.getText();
                System.out.println(str_job_desc);
            }
            try
            {
                // closes the pop up that appears 
                driver.findElement(By.id("popover-x-button")).click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {


            }

            try
            {
                //click on next link to go to next page
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'np')][contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();

                //scroll down
                JavascriptExecutor jse1 = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                jse1.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)", "");
            }
            //when I get the exception(because no next link is available) exit.
            catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestion.

Comment: Ummm... don't use `System.exit()`?  There shouldn't be any reason ever to use this in a JUnit test.  (There's almost never a reason to ever use it in Java, period.)  But I don't understand what you're trying to test for.  If the exception occurs, does that mean the test fails?  Does that mean you want to exit the loop?  If you just want to exit the `while` loop, use `break;`.  Other than that, I can't offer any advice since it's not clear at all what your passing and failing criteria are.

Comment: print job description from pages that are being populated by the url. When I reach the 3rd page and job descriptions have been printed stop the code. If I do not use the exit() it keeps on printing job description from the last page(in this case 3rd page) over and over again, the test never stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually re-use the trick used in your code to avoid try-catch block

```
List<WebElement> popXButton=driver.findElements(By.id("popover-x-button"));
     if (popXButton.size()>0){
         driver.findElement(By.id("popover-x-button")).click();
     }
```

Same extends to the next block too

```
List<WebElement> nextVal=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'np')][contains(text(),'Next')]"));
if(nextVal.size()>0){
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'np')][contains(text(),'Next')]")).click();
}
else{
  break;//exits while loop!
}
```